# how to import any type of file(CSV,XLS,XLSX,txt) into jqgrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, struts2

I want to import from an .xls file into jqgrid...

I have an idea but I don't know how to implement it, because no direct method is there for import,

1. select the file from particular location
2. convert the file into java object like (list,array list etc)
3. then convert java object to json object
4. pass that json object in grid model inside jquery grid.

suggest me how to implement...

Comment: google search java csv parser...should find lots of information

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Temporary Table as tables gives you more navigation flexibility and inter-table transfers. Array values will be lost when the page is closed (intentionally or accidentally). However, few things which you need to look at it that

- The fields available in the XLS file are Pre-Defined/Static or Dynamic
- If Pre-Defined/Static fields, then pre-create a temporary table and then use it to import the file. When you want to move the imported contents to another table, just use SQL commands to import and empty the temporary table contents.
- If Dynamic fields, then you need to create a temporary tables at runtime and then destroy the table on the data transfer to another table (if needed).

Based on your choice, bind the JQGrid ColModels accordingly. In case of Dynamic, you need to fetch the field names in a variable first before the Grid is loaded, but in Static fields case, just define it manually during design time.

I generally apply this approach. Hope it will be helpful.